# Page Flip animation like iBooks in swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, storyboard, ibooks

I have been searching a lot about coding the view transition animation. But I am most interested on the book page flipping animation on the iBooks. May I know is there any available sources for that which is written in swift? 
Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done with the UIPageViewController class. See here:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_Swift_iOS_8_UIPageViewController_Application

Answer (score 2):

Please look in this turorial.

http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

For the page turn effect you need to go in Interface Builder and select page curl for your UIPageViewController.